# is it a good practice to put a war file image into docker containers?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I have a Spring-boot application which I want to deploy and run using docker. Is it a good practice to put war file images in the container or it is better to put jar ones? why?

P.S. Once I read that it is better to "make jars , not wars"  :-) but do not know the reason behind it.

Comment: you can put jar, war, sar, or any kind of file in the docker.  depends upon what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: so for a spring-boot app , both ways are common practices ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the main reasons for building a docker image for your application is to provide an artefact that people can run without installing and managing external software dependencies (like an app server to run a war file).

From a container user perspective, it makes no difference whether you package your code in a jar or a war file or as a fortran binary. All they do is run a container image.

From your perspective, of doing the Docker build and config management, the packaging of a jar file and copying into a container would be a simpler solution than trying to setup and configure an app server for packaging, then deploying each release into the app server. That being said, users would probably prefer the more complete app server solution, because that may be easier for them the run the application.

See [Ohmens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660993/1318694) for some more technical components of the java build process

Comment: Thanks Matt ! very comprehensive !

Answer (score 7):

Matt's answer is correct, but you have to consider some further points.

- **Updates to the applicationserver:** docker images of tomcat or glassfish are maintained by the responsible companies. If they find a nasty (security) bug they fix it and push a new version of that image to docker hub. To update your container to that secure version all you have to do is to rebuild your image and run a new version. If you bundle the applicationserver inside a `jar` you have to recompile your whole project to use that updated version. BTW most applicationservers have a autodeploy mechanism to deploy war's easily.
- **Dockers cache:** if you build an image from a java base image and simply copy your fat jar on it, your whole image consists of one big layer. If you build another version of your app the big jar file changes causing docker to create another big layer. These two big layers both need space on your disc. On the other hand if you deploy a "small" war file to an applicationserver the two images share all layers until the layer with the war file. With these mechanism does docker improve your disc usage and speed up build times.

Comment: Thanks Ohmen ! Even more comprehensive ! :-)

Comment: Im writing my thesis about this topic so your welcome :-D

Comment: @Ohmen Would you consider an app recompile to be significantly worse than updating your docker build for the new app server and deploy?

Comment: Good point on the cache. The fat jars can be [made a bit more docker friendly](https://bsideup.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/spring-boots-fat-jars-vs-docker.html).

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the link i did not know that. But if your app is not only three classes big and uses some sophisticated Buildprocess (dependencies, Env, Secrets, legacy parts) you are happy if you do not have to test again all those integrations with the new build. In case of a small maven build or a well defined CD/CI pipeline you are right it does not matter.

Comment: check out my gradle plugin to automate docker layer cache with spring boot war or jar [https://github.com/gclayburg/dockerPreparePlugin](https://github.com/gclayburg/dockerPreparePlugin)

Comment: I feel like the argument about layering prompts the question whether "one JAR per application" is a good model for Docker _at all_. For instance, if my WAR for Tomcat is 150MB, I don't make best use of layering between versions where few classes change.

Comment: @Raphael Hi, Docker consists of waaayy more than just the layer thingy... Its main advantage in comparison to plain jar deployments is that once you have a image/container, you or your ops team do not have to care what’s inside. Be it java, go or python, you can handle them all the same way. That’s btw what Kubernetes does. How you structure your app within the container is ultimately your own decision.